# how to upload each item from array's object with `this` keyword

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I have an array something like this:

```js
let arr = [
   {
     num: 10,
     reload: () => {
         this.num = 30;
     }

   },
   {
     num: 40,
     reload: () => {
         this.num = 20;
     }

   }
]
```

then I am trying to run this code

```
arr.forEach(item => {
   item.reload()
})
```

I want the array's first object to have `num` = 30 and second one as `num = 20`

`this` doesn't seen to work..

Comment: `this` does not exist in arrow functions. Use regular functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let arr = [
  {
    num: 10,
    reload: function(){
      this.num = 30;
    }

  },
  {
    num: 40,
    reload: function(){
      this.num = 20;
    }

  }
]


arr.forEach(item => {
  item.reload()
})

console.warn(arr);
```